# Integral $ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x + y}\,dx\,dy $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x + y}\,dx\,dy
$$

is

(A) infinite
 (B) finite, but cannot be evaluated in closed form
 (C) $1$
 (D) $2$

I have tried with integration by parts in succession and ending up with value $1/2$. But there is no such option. The correct option is (C) $1$.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Plz change the title to the more descriptive one. :-)

Comment: are you sure that your integral nconverges?

Comment: If you post your calculation, we could try to check.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-x-y)}{x+y}dx=\int_y^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-u)}{u}du=F(y)$, for $y>0$; in addition, we have that $F^{\prime}(y)=-\frac{\exp(-y)}{y}$. Now you want $I=\int_0^{+\infty}F(y)dy$.

Integrating by parts, we have $$\int_{\varepsilon}^A F(y)dy=[yF(y)]_{\varepsilon}^A+\int_{\varepsilon}^A \exp(-y)dy$$
It is clear that $\int_{\varepsilon}^A \exp(-y)dy \to \int_0^{+\infty}\exp(-y)dy=1$ if $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $A\to +\infty$. It remains to study $yF(y)$ for $y\to +\infty$ and for $y\to 0$.

a) For $y\to +\infty$: use that $\frac{\exp(-u)}{u}\leq \frac{\exp(-u)}{y}$ for $u\geq y$.

b) For $y\to 0$:
use that
$$yF(y)=y\int_y^1\frac{\exp(-u)-1}{u}du-y\log y+y\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-u)}{u}du$$